# Dynamic PIVOT two columns prefix

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-pivot

Database: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

I have one table that contains the computers and the software installed.
Now, one computer can have 30+ software installed but there are probably 100+ different software on the infrastructure.

This is a representation of the table

```
Computer  | Software
--------------------
PC123     | Office
PC123     | Firefox
PC456     | Office
PC456     | Firefox
PC456     | CAD
PC789     | Firefox
PC789     | Outlook
...
```

I'm looking for a result that would look like this

```
Computer  | Software 1 | Software 2 | Software 3 
------------------------------------------------
PC123     | Firefox    | Office     | NULL
PC456     | CAD        | Firefox    | Office
PC789     | Firefox    | Outlook    | NULL
...
```

I've been looking into dynamic PIVOT but I'm still new with SQL.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are countless examples of dynamic pivots here, however, I understand sometimes we all need a little jump-start.

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(concat('Software ',Row_Number() over (Partition By Computer Order By Software))) From Yourtable  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select [Computer],' + @SQL + '
From (
       Select Computer
             ,Software
             ,Col      = concat(''Software '',Row_Number() over (Partition By Computer Order By Software))
       From YourTable
     ) A
Pivot (max([software]) For [Col] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

**Returns**

```
Computer    Software 1  Software 2  Software 3
PC123       Firefox     Office      NULL
PC456       CAD         Firefox     Office
PC789       Firefox     Outlook     NULL
```

---

**If it helps, the generated SQL looks like this:**

```
Select [Computer],[Software 1],[Software 2],[Software 3]
From (
       Select Computer
             ,Software
             ,Col      = concat('Software ',Row_Number() over (Partition By Computer Order By Software))
       From YourTable
     ) A
Pivot (max([software]) For [Col] in ([Software 1],[Software 2],[Software 3]) ) p
```

Comment: This worked great. I modified **Row_Number() over (Partition By Computer Order By Software)** for **RIGHT('10000' + Row_Number() over (Partition By Computer Order By Software),2)** to fix the order past Software 10

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use the stuff function and put all of the software into one line.
My code might be slightly off. I suck without being able to test.

```
Results should look like this:
Computer    Software
PC123       Firefox, CAD, Office        
PC456       Firefox


SELECT t.Computer, Software_String.Software
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Computer FROM TABLE) t
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT REPLACE(STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + w.Start_Date, 100) 
            FROM Computer w
            WHERE c.Computer_ID = w.Computer_ID
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 2, ''), '  ', ' ') [Software]
        ) Software_String
```

Or you can use a case statement instead of pivots. I find pivot programming slow and a pain to write.